# Python double question mark %% magic commands vs single %

Tags: ipython

What is the difference between magic commands in Python starting with single `%` or double question `%%` mark?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but "magic" methods are not part of pure python. They're an addon provided by IPython.

Answer (score 2):

> Magic commands come in two flavors: line magics, which are denoted by
>   a single % prefix and operate on a single line of input, and cell
>   magics, which are denoted by a double %% prefix and operate on
>   multiple lines of input.

More details: [Python Magic Commands](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.03-magic-commands.html)